# Xna keeping player from overlaping parts of map

Tags: c#, xna

I had an idea in my game of having 3 layers to the map, the first being the ground, the second being the roads/grass/etc, and the third being impassable objects such as walls/buildings/lakes/rivers/trees. I have it so the player is centered at the middle of the screen and the layers of the map move in the inverse direction that the player wants to go. I was thinking I would have the different layers that way if the playerModel overlaps whereever something is drawn on the impassableLayer, then the playerModel would shift back. However, as I am new to xna, I don't know how to get the game to recognize that the playerModel is overlapping the impassable objects on the impassableLayer. The impassableLayer obviously only has objects drawn on it, and is empty anywhere there isn't an object. Therefore I can't just say:

```
if (playerModel.X > impassableLayer.X)
{
   impassableLayer.X++;
}
```

As this would always be true.

Is there a way to tell if an object is overlapping a layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is collision detection I belive. You want to keep objects from passing through each other. It isnt as simple as the idea you had. True collision detection will take alot of work, but their are tons of tutorials for it.

- [Youtube tutorial on per pixel collision](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=asU7afngQ8U)
- [Per-pixel collision on MSDN](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/tutorial/collision_2d_perpixel_transformed)
- [Bounding Box Collision](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180069-xna-2d-bounding-box-collision-detection/)

You can always to a search here on the site or google, there are lots of resources for this out there.

Comment: So does this mean I would have to instantiate each Building/lake/tree and place them on the map with individual coordinates? That's seems Like it would take up a lot of time and memory because if I was to have 10,000 trees on the map, the game would have to first create each of the 10,000 trees and then place them on the map, right?

Comment: Yes you would, however, in computing, 10,000 is not alot. I have over 20 million objects in my game.

Comment: I see, looking at this pixel collision stuff so far though it looks like its saying if the "object" is touching transparent pixels it doesn't count as a collision right? So can I not still use this method since the only non transparent pixels on the layer are those of objects?

Comment: You don't have to use the same layer, you can compare multiple layers, or whatver you want.